# How to store the information in a 'NoType' HTML element in Selenium - Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm trying to take some information from an HTML element using Selenium - Python, and I'm unsure on how to save it. I'm kind of new to programming, but literate enough to where I know how to write code, but it's hard to research answers and adapt those to my code. I've looked on Google and can't seem to find anything that would help me specifically with what I need.

Here is the HTML element I need to get information from:

```
<span id="ctl00_plnMain_rptAssigmnetsByCourse_ctl00_lblOverallAverage">99.05</span>
```

I need to retrieve the 99.05 and store it in a variable named "avg."

Here is my code I have for the Selenium test.

```
username = raw_input("Username: ")
password = raw_input("Password: ")  
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox    
browser.get("https://hac.mckinneyisd.net/homeaccess/default.aspx") # Load page
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$plnMain$txtLogin") # Find the query box
elem.send_keys(username)
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$plnMain$txtPassword") # Find the password box
elem.send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(0.2) # Let the page load
elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Classwork").click()
time.sleep(0.2)
???????????????
browser.close()
```

What should I put in the ???... to take the 99.05 from the object and save it as "avg?" I have tried:

```
content = elem.text("td[@id='ctl00....lblOverallAverage']"
```

...but I get an error saying that I can't do that because it has no type.

Comment: Check my comment under @nrbafna's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_plnMain_rptAssigmnetsByCourse_ctl00_lblOverallAverage")
avg = elem.getText()
```

Comment: Hmm... Now I get this error. "TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable"

Comment: @nrbafna, `text` is an attribute not a method; so yo should change your last line to `avg = elem.text`. @Justin Potts, the error you mentioned is actually about what I said.